# Javascript number counter with cache

Tags: javascript

I have this script for to increment a counter by one after 1 second , but when I refresh the page I need to remember the last number I counted.

Example: Currently, I have 40. When I refresh the page I need to start counting after 40 not reset to 1. Is this possible?

```js
function animateValue(id) {
  var obj = document.getElementById(id);
  var current = parseInt(obj.innerHTML);
  setInterval(function() {
    current++;
    // Update the contents of the element
    obj.innerHTML = current;
  }, 1000);
}

animateValue('value');
```

```html
<h1>
  <div id="value">1</div>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can store the counter progress in [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), then retrieve the value on page load and start counting from there:

```js
var obj = document.getElementById("value");
let counterStorage = localStorage.getItem('counter')
if(counterStorage) obj.innerHTML = counterStorage

function animateValue(id) {
    var current = parseInt(obj.innerHTML);
    setInterval(function() {
        current++;
        localStorage.setItem('counter', current)
        obj.innerHTML = current;
    }, 1000);
}

animateValue('value');
```

Comment: May I suggest setting the local storage item in a dedicated `window.onbeforeunload` event handler rather than every second, within the `setInterval`?

Comment: @secan That would indeed be a more efficient approach. The only caveat with that is if the user decides to open the page again without leaving the previous page, causing the timer to still start from 1.

Comment: When i have high number like 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

<div class="valor" id="value">100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000</div> appears this : 1e+47 How can remove this rounding?

Answer (score 2):

Use localstorage. If not exists then set and if exists use the value from localstorage.

```js
function animateValue(id){    
    const obj = document.getElementById(id);
    let current = parseInt(obj.innerHTML);
    const storageTime = localStorage.getItem("mytime")
    if ( storageTime === null) {
       localStorage.setItem("mytime", current); 
    } else {
      current = storageTime;
    }
    
    setInterval(function(){        
        current++;
        localStorage.setItem("mytime", current); 
        // Update the contents of the element
        obj.innerHTML = current;
    },1000);
}

animateValue('value');
```

```html
 <h1><div id="value">1</div></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `window.localstorage`. the code will look something like this

```js
window.localstorage.setItem('timer', timer)
```